# Convert OCTET_STRING_t to NSData?

Tags: ios, objective-c, types, hex, nsdata

I have an `OCTET_STRING_t` that contains binary data. I am loading up apple's app store receipt data using ASN1C. Here is some example code:

```
// Walk the attributes
for (i = 0; i < payload->list.count; i++) {
    ReceiptAttribute_t *entry = payload->list.array[i];
    switch (entry->type) {
         case 5: // 5 = hash
         OCTET_STRING_t *hash = &entry->value;
         break;
         ...
    }
}
```

What is the proper way toconvert it to an NSData container?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `OCTET_STRING_t` is the same as [this one](http://sourcecodebrowser.com/asn1c/0.9.16/_o_c_t_e_t___s_t_r_i_n_g_8h.html#struct_o_c_t_e_t___s_t_r_i_n_g) then simply:

```
OCTET_STRING_t *hash = &entry->value;
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:hash->buf
                                      length:hash->size];
```